# Sum all rows in a column if column header meets certain text criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Say I have 5 column headers that repeat 3 times. Apples, Oranges, Bananas, Grapes, Plums, Apples, Oranges, Bananas...etc. The headers are all in row 2. Underneath (Row 3 - Row 230) each header are counts.

I want to sum all of the counts underneath each column where the header is "Apples".

I'm using this formula: `=SUMIF(I2:AW2,"Apples",I3:AW230)`

The SUM I get back is off by a large factor. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT((I2:AW2="Apples")*I3:AW230)
```

One note to this, if there are any text or errors in `I3:AW230` this will error.

if there is text or error we need to resort to an array formula of SUM:

```
=SUM(IFERROR((I2:AW2="Apples")*I3:AW230,0))
```

Being an array formula and depending on one's version of Excel this may need to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter when exiting edit mode.

---

If one has the Dynamic Formula FILTER then they can use:

```
=SUM(FILTER(I3:AW230,I2:AW2="Apples"))
```

Comment: There is text. Is there a way to account for this?